# Change Padding in Selector drawable

Tags: android, selector, drawable, padding

i am trying to change the padding from a Button in a custom drawable ressource, and reuse this in a selector.
Changing the drawable seems not the Problem, but the App always use the highest padding aviable from the different drawables:

button_inactive.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#FF4d681f" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="2dp"
    android:left="2dp"
    android:right="2dp"
    android:top="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

        <padding
            android:bottom="5dp"
            android:top="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

button_active.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#FF4D681F" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="2dp"
    android:left="2dp"
    android:right="2dp"
    android:top="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#FF8da32d" />

        <padding
            android:bottom="10dp"
            android:top="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

button_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/button_active"/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_active"/>
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_active"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_inactive"/>
```

The Problem is that my Button uses the 10dp padding in all states, including the "inactive" state.

Is there a Solution to get it working only with XML or it is better to make a custom Button programaticly?

Comment: I tried it with one of my drawable buttons.  The normal one has no padding, and I added padding to the pressed one.  It uses the padding from the pressed one even when displaying the normal one.  I am also having a problem with .png files I am using in the same way.  I made the pressed one larger than the normal one, but the size does not change.  This sucks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19227057/1645319

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="@android:color/black" />

<padding
    android:bottom="10dp"
    android:left="10dp"
    android:right="10dp"
    android:top="10dp" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="6dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="6dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="6dp"
    android:topRightRadius="6dp" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Add `android:variablePadding="true"` attribute to your selector.

I'm not sure how (and if) is this working when you are using layer-list, however I decided to share it anyway for anyone looking for the answer (as I was).

Comment: android:variablePadding is buggy atribute and has never worked.