# Remove text padding in Button view

Tags: android, android-button

I would like to remove the padding around text in Button view.
The first screenshot is the result I would achieve, and the second one is the state of the art.

[image]

[image]

Of course, I have defined a custom drawable to get the button appearance. But even if I set the padding attribute to 0dp the result does not change.

Any suggestion, please?

**EDIT**
Here is the xml code of the button

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        style="@style/dark_header_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@android:string/cancel" />
```

Here is the style xml file:

```
<style name="dark_header_button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bkg_dark_header_button</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">-1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">1</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

and here is the drawable xml file:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>

        <corners android:radius="10dp" />

        <gradient 
            android:angle="90" 
            android:endColor="#060606"
            android:startColor="#707070"
            android:type="linear" />

    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>

        <corners android:radius="10dp" />

        <gradient 
            android:angle="90" 
            android:endColor="#707070" 
            android:startColor="#060606" 
            android:type="linear" />

        <stroke 
            android:width="0.5dp" 
            android:color="#2b2b2b" />

    </shape>
</item>


</selector>
```

Comment: mind to share your xml too....?

Comment: "Of course, I have defined a custom drawable to get the button appearance" Please show us this definition, if you define your own there should be no padding

Comment: Do you have your `layout_height` attribute set as `wrap_content`? And make sure you 9 patched images.

Comment: Sorry guys I forgot the code.
@yugidroid it is and xml drawable so no 9-patch. And yes, `layout_height` is set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button text doesn't need padding, it is by default in center of the button.
I think you are using the `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"` in the manifest file, please remove it and use native app Theme and try it.

Comment: Thank you!! It was set Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar by default.

Comment: And what if you don't want a title/action bar?

Answer (score 57):

Its not actually padding but the theme is setting a minHeight and minWidth for button widgets. You can completely remove this effect without changing your theme by setting the following on your button in the xml:

```
android:minHeight="0dp"
android:minWidth="0dp"
```

It thus also implies that you can play around with different settings for different effects, 0dp is merely an example to completely remove this effect.

Answer (score 19):

you can try using [android:includeFontPadding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aincludeFontPadding). set it to false. also set the padding to 0.